# What AWS Policies should I select for an admin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies

Unde IAM, I am setting up new users. For admin, what policies should I select to start with & what permissions should i set as part of best practices?

[Click to view image](https://gyazo.com/2d5570ece42a1bb5922e4e3ae282d2f2)

Comment: I would start with [Security best practices in IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html). Also, please don't post links to external images.

Comment: It can be helpful for it [Creating your first IAM admin user and group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/getting-started_create-admin-group.html)

Answer (score 2):

As an admin I would select `AdministratorAccess`. Best practice is [least privilege](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege), but as an admin you actually want to have full access I suppose. You could also add `Billing` if you want the admin to have access to the billing as well.

If you want to dig deeper, you can read more on that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/getting-started_create-admin-group.html).